# Why does Process.WaitForExit() sometimes hang though called upon an exited process?

Tags: .net, process, exit

We have seen that rarely .net's `Process.WaitForExit()` seems buggy: `p.WaitForExit()` does not return even though the process created by Process.Start() *has exited*, and `p.WaitForExit(0)` has previously returned false.

What could cause this to happen - is there a known limitation of the Process class, or of the WaitForExit method?

Note, that we have a process dump where this happened, and funcOutput does not appear in any of the thread stacks, suggesting it is not a self-inflicted deadlock from failing to handle process standard output/error.

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo si = p.StartInfo;
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.FileName = filename;
si.Arguments = args;
si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
si.RedirectStandardError = true;

object l = new object();
var funcOutput = new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => {
    lock (l) {
        string val = e.Data;
        output.WriteLine(val);
    }
});
p.ErrorDataReceived += funcOutput;
p.OutputDataReceived += funcOutput;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
if (!p.WaitForExit(0)) {

    // code that successfully kills process when passed p.Id...
    p.WaitForExit(); // hangs 4eva
}
```

Comment: Post the code you're talking about. Process output, stream redirection will cause deadlock if not done properly.

Comment: Is the lock object `l` held by any other thread and never released? Basically the process will never end until you read both the streams fully. You can confirm that with a task manager.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, the lock is not being held while WaitForExit hangs.

Comment: Related blog post: http://alabaxblog.info/2013/06/redirectstandardoutput-beginoutputreadline-pattern-broken/ Similar experience from other guy. You may find it helpful.